# iMacros + extract values + save in csv

Tags: csv, imacros

I'm extracting 2 values for 10 products from a website: price and dimensions.
I'm saving the result in a CSV file.

But,
when I open the CSV, the result is 10 rows with 1 column, containing: price, dimensions
How can I have 10 rows with 2 columns, whith column1 containing price and column2 containing dimensions?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: if the price and dimensions are in 2 different TAG elements, than they should be already separated since you apply them 2 EXTRACT=TXT. Imacros will put a comma between them. but if there is only one TAG element that contains both, than you'll have to do some spliting, if possible. I can't really say without seeing the actual code

Comment: You can open the result csv file in any plain-text editor to determine if this is the excel (other spreadsheet processor) problem or the matter is with your code.